# Recursively find the path to all leaves descending from a given parent in a tree

Tags: postgresql, recursive, hierarchy, tree, graph

I'm trying to write a query to identify the path to each furthest descendant of a particular parent node in a table of tree structures like:

```
    0     1
    |     |
    2     3
    |     |
    4     5
   / \    |
 *6*  8  *7*
      |
     *9*
```

There are many parents, all children have one parent, parents have 0-5 children (but the graph is very "long" – most parents only have one child). There are no cycles.

I'm trying to efficiently identify the path to the furthest descendants of a specific node (and not to any intermediate nodes). E.g. in the above:

- `get_leaf_paths(1)` would return 1 row: `{1, 3, 5, 7}`
- `get_leaf_paths(2)` would return 2 rows: `{2, 4, 6}` and `{2, 4, 8, 9}`

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE graph (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES graph(id)
);
INSERT INTO graph (id, parent_id)
    VALUES (0, NULL),
           (1, NULL),
           (2, 0),
           (3, 1),
           (4, 2),
           (5, 3),
           (6, 4),
           (7, 5),
           (8, 4),
           (9, 8);
```

I'm hoping for a result that looks something like:

```
SELECT get_leaf_paths.* FROM get_leaf_paths(0);
path
-----
{0, 2, 4, 6}
{0, 2, 4, 8, 9}
(2 rows)
```

In my [initial attempt](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289512/drop-intermediate-results-of-recursive-query-in-postgres) at a function with a recursive query, I've had trouble selecting only the furthest leaves, especially since some branches are shorter than others (e.g. `6` and `9` above are at different depths). The paths can be very deep (thousands or millions of elements), so I would also like to avoid the excessive memory usage of generating paths for every intermediate node.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                parent_id, 
                id::TEXT path,
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                             FROM graph gr
                             WHERE graph.id = gr.parent_id ) is_leaf
                FROM graph 
                WHERE id = 2 /* initital node id */
         UNION ALL
         SELECT graph.id, 
                graph.parent_id, 
                cte.path || ',' || graph.id,
                NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                             FROM graph gr
                             WHERE graph.id = gr.parent_id ) 
         FROM cte JOIN graph ON cte.id = graph.parent_id)
SELECT path 
FROM cte
WHERE is_leaf
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e40ff454f302033bf5e8cba8b0b0d85

Multiple initial nodes may be applied too (`WHERE id IN (0, 1)`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This seems to produce a path for every intermediate node too – when running this query for a node with ~1 million children, would you expect it to waste a lot of memory, or can Postgres avoid creating all those unused paths? Or is there another way to optimize this for very long paths?

Comment: *can Postgres avoid creating all those unused paths?* Noway. CTE must collect ALL rows, that's outer query which eliminates intermediate rows. If this is often-executed task then update your table structure and store FQP in it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by FQP? How could I update the table structure to make this more efficient? (Thanks!)

Comment: Fully Qualified Path. I.e. each node stores additionally full path to the root node. In this case the query will be simple - CTE not needed, you only check that initial node is present in FQP and the node have no childs.

Comment: Alternatively, if the most nodes have only one child, you may compact your table and store the structure `(id, parent_id, intermediate_ids)` where `intermediate_ids` is a chain of 1-child nodes (i.e. you'll store only roots, leafs and multi-child nodes rows).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!